# Is Nexus 7 2013 LTE usable as a phablet?

Tags: nexus-7, nexus-5

I've stepped into a B&M the other day, and they had Nexus 7 in stock; I've realised how small it is, and it occurred to me that it might be usable as a phablet.

Other than being unable to use voice over 2G/3G (and 4G?), and size distinctions, are there any other features that are different between Nexus 7 and Nexus 5, especially as far as phone usage would be concerned?

Comment: I assume that when paired with a bluetooth headset, you'd be set. It doesn't have a handset speaker as far as I'm aware, so you wouldn't be able to hold it to your head and talk on it.

Answer (score 3):

Besides being unable to make traditional voice calls, one difference is there is no earpiece, so unless you have headphones, your VoIP calls, video chats, etc... will all be on speaker.  Since it is a tablet, it's obvious why you wouldn't have one and it would look crazy holding that giant thing up to your ear.  Another  difference that people also tend to overlook is SMS.  Since there is no phone number associated with the tablet you won't get SMS service.  That can be mitigated by using services such as Google Voice which uses data instead of the SMS protocol to send these messages but yet are delivered to the recipient as SMS messages.

Due to the above you'll be missing the phone and messaging app components of the android OS on the nexus 7 (although as of 4.4 messaging app has been integrated with hangouts). Also you'll have support for multiple user profiles on your tablet, which is not an option on android phones.

BTW, you'll probably need to wear cargo pants to accommodate a Nexus 7, as it would probably be too large in your front pocket for you to sit comfortably.